# $.ajax call PHP include file return 500 error internal

Tags: php, jquery

here is it my code i call ajax by jquery $.ajax
js

```
$("#form-login").submit(function(){
    var email = $("#menu_username");
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "register_cmd.php",
        data: {email:email},
        dataType: "json",
        cache:false,
        success:function(data){
            if(data.c == "ok"){
                window.location.reload();
            } else {
                alert(data);
            }
            return false;
        }
    })
});
```

register_cmd.php

```
<?PHP
include 'system/library/main.php';

$main = new mainQuery();

$chk_email = $main->checkEmail($email);
?>
```

main.php

```
function checkEmail($email){
    $result = "function here";
    return $result;
}
```

then it return 500 internal server error i don't know why

Comment: Check your apache error log, there you will get some information on why it is giving 500 error. Also you can check file permission. OR you can check by directly going to register_cmd.php?email=email and see how it behaves.

Comment: i check error log it's nothing error,
then i go to check permission it's ok 777,
and i check directly it's return to index.php because register_cmd.php return 500 error

Comment: Clear your browser's cache, Delete your browser's cookies.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem myself, even though i couldn't find the reason for it in my case, when changing from POST to GET, the problem 500 error disappeared!

because GET method sends the encoded user information appended to the page request.

```
type:'POST'
```

to

```
type:'GET'
```

Answer (score 0):

I doing little changes in your codes. Just try this

```
 var email = $("#menu_username").val(); // if you want to take the value from email field
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "register_cmd.php",
    data: {email:email},
    dataType: "json",
    cache:false,
    success:function(data){
        if(data.result == "ok"){
            window.location.reload();
        } else {
            alert(data.result);
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

AND change the codes in register_cmd.php as follows

```
 <?PHP
  include 'system/library/main.php';
  $main = new mainQuery();
  $chk_email['result'] = $main->checkEmail($email);
  print_r(json_encode($chk_email)); // if you are using json, you should use json_encode before it returns.  
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

the function in main.php need's a class arround it

```
class mainQuery {
    public function checkEmail($email){
        $result = "function here";
        return $result; 
    }
}
```

otherwise you cannot instance `new mainQUery;`

also on top of everything to debug set

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
```

`500` are serverside errors and have nothing to do with ajax.

probably this line:

```
var email = $("#menu_username");
```

might have to be

```
var email = $("#menu_username").text();
//or
var email = $("#menu_username").val();
```

It doesn't matter if it's a `POST` or `GET` request.